How to add X-Original-Forwarded-For as request header in NGINX Ingress Controller?
I am using F5 NGINX Ingress Controller.
Note: I am not using Kubernetes community edition ( Ingress-nginx)
I have achieved traffic splitting using Virtual server for NGINX Ingress Controller. However in the production some clients are using ip whitelisting and in order to pass the request we use header X-Original-Forwarded-For
I want to set X-Original-Forwarded-For request header in NGINX Ingress Controller
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/#configmap-and-virtualservervirtualserverroute-resources
According to above link setting on ingress level it affects virtual server too.
I am using helm and env.yaml to isntallnginx ingress controller we until now no luck
env.yaml
# Traffic split Nginx Ingress 
controller:
  replicaCount: 2
  config:
    log-format-upstream: '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_length $request_time [$proxy_upstream_name] [$proxy_alternative_upstream_name] $upstream_addr $upstream_response_length $upstream_response_time $upstream_status $req_id'
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: "xxx.xxxx.xxxx"
    externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: "xxxxxxx"
      nginx.org/location-snippets: |
         more_set_input_headers "X-Original-Forwarded-For: jatin";


helm command to install
helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress \
  --version 1.0.2 -n nginx-ingress --create-namespace \
  --set controller.ingressClass.create=true \
  --set controller.ingressClass.name=nginx-ingress \
  --set controller.ingressClass.setAsDefaultIngress=false \
  -f ./nginx-ingress/env/env.yaml

Even tried adding on the virtual server resource as shown here
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  namespace: xxxxxx
  name: nginx-vs-traffic-split
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress

spec:
  host: xxxxx.com
  upstreams:
  - name: xxxxx-a
    service: xxxx-a
    port: 80
  - name: xxxx-b
    service: xxxx-b
    port: 80
  - name: xxxx-c
    service: xxxx-c
    port: 80
  routes:
  - path: /
    location-snippets: |
      add_header my-test-header test-value;   
    splits:
    # The sum of the weights of all splits must be equal to 100
    - weight: 33
      action:
        pass: xxxxx-a
    - weight: 33
      action:
        pass: xxxx-b
    - weight: 34
      action:
        pass: xxxxx-c 

Update:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/ingress-nginx/#migration-with-kubernetes-ingress-resources
I saw this link where configuration-snippet is used location-snippets inside nginx
I tried even with this still no luck

So you're saying that nginx.org/location-snippets annotation within your Helm values configuration and your VirtualServer resource didn't fix the issue? Also you've checked your env.yaml Helm values file includes the necessary configuration for adding the X-Original-Forwarded-For header?

After reading https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header I understood which headers need to be added to the request headers.
I solved it by enabling snippets on the nginx-ingress ( as snippets are disabled by default) on helm chart and added location-snippets on virtual-server resource
Command for enabling snippets
helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress \
  --set controller.enableSnippets=true \
  --version 1.0.2 -n nginx-ingress --create-namespace \
  --set controller.ingressClass.create=true \
  --set controller.ingressClass.name=nginx-ingress \
  --set controller.ingressClass.setAsDefaultIngress=false \
  -f ./nginx-ingress/env/env.yaml

Virtual server resource
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: nginx-vs-traffic-split
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress
spec:
  host: {{.Values.domain.my-domain}}
  upstreams:
  - name: web-nginx 
    service: web-nginx 
    port: 80
  - name: web-octane 
    service: web-octane 
    port: 80
  - name: web 
    service: web 
    port: 80
  routes:
  - path: /
    splits:    
    # Header configuration is required for customers who use IP whitelist feature.
    # If this configuration is not present then all the requests will be blocked.
    location-snippets: |
      proxy_set_header 'X-Original-Forwarded-For' '$http_x_azure_clientip';
    splits: 
    # The sum of the weights of all splits must be equal to 100   
    - weight: {{.Values.trafficSplitWeight.nginx}}
      action:
        pass: web-nginx 



log-format-upstream is a Commnunity Ingress Controller config map key. As you are using NGINX Ingress Controller, the key you are looking for is log-format. These config map keys that relate to logging are listed here.
Make sure to add the header which contains the original ip also to the log format.
config:
    log-format: '$http_x_original_forwarded_for ...'


Thank for your answer but i wanted to add for header for request headers. I tried this but it didn't help.
